# raster statistics by line shape (vector)

Tags: raster, statistics, shapefile, advanced-license-level

I have a georeferenced area where I created 7 raster maps (classified with suitability values from 1 to 5) as I have 7 factors to check e.g. natural reserves, floods, slopes etc. From there I did a weighted overlay raster for the final evaluation. In this area I have a railway corridor (represented by a line) which I buffer at 30 meters. I want to calculate a suitability score from the cells that this buffer contains. For example if the buffer contains 10 cells with value 1, 10 with 2, 20 with 3, 20 with 4 and 40 with 5, the final score will be: (10*1)+(10*2)+(20*3)+(20*4)+(40*5) = 370 points of suitability.

How can I count the number of cells from each value this buffer "touches" and the final sum? If in some way I could clip the raster with the buffer, the new raster of the buffer should contain "value" and "count" and I suppose I could do it from there.
I don't know if I need to do the buffer or it can be done with the line shape, since the raster already contains cells of 30m*30m.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Spatial Analyst extension for ArcGIS, then you may consider this approach:

1. Convert your buffered polygons to a raster layer using the **[Polygon to Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000030000000)** tool. The result will be a Boolean image of 1's and 0's, with cells with value 1 being within the buffered area.
2. Use the **[Combine](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Combine/009z0000007r000000/)** tool to get the cell count for each class within the buffered area.

Other useful tools for summary statistics include **Extract by Polygon** and **Zonal Statistics**. Zonal Statistics will also require rasterization of the buffered area before use.

Comment: This was really helpful. Thank you very much WhiteboxDev :)

Comment: @MichailG. I'm glad that it was helpful and good luck with your analysis.